# iAd error Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iad

when i go to my developer Account and klick on iAd, I get this error:

[image]

I have only 1 App approved and I didn't change anything for the past 7 days. (It worked before, no changes made).

Comment: Same here.  I'm trying to make my first iAd. It's been like that for at least the past couple of days. The error seems to indicate some sort of crash (500 error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's appare that some user has some problems when they access from itunes connect. But if you use this link: 
https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/#app_homepage
should work correctly.